# Ruby Infinite Loop

Tags: ruby

I'm currently learning ruby, and I've gotten stuck on this problem:

Write a Deaf Grandma program. Whatever you say to grandma (whatever you type in), she should respond with  HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!, unless you shout it (type in all capitals). If you shout, she can hear you and yells back, NO, NOT SINCE 1938! To make your program really believable, have grandma shout a different year each time; maybe any year at random between 1930 and 1950. You can't stop talking to grandma until you shout BYE.

This is the code I tried:

```
puts "Say something to Grandma!"
something = gets.chomp
while something != "BYE"
    if something == something.upcase
      puts "NO, NOT SINCE 19" + (rand(30..50)).to_s + "!"
    else
      puts "HUH? SPEAK UP SONNY!"
    end
end
```

Whenever I execute this, the if and else strings just go on an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't speak ruby, but you're `gets`ing once and *then* starting the `while`. That is bound to lead to an infinite loop, because `something` will never change. You probably have to gets inside the `while` statement so it gets's every time. Also `chomp` is the coolest command I've ever seen in a scripting language.

Comment: @Pekka: `chomp` - chomps the newline off. `gets` - this one gets user input. For future reference. :)

Comment: @Sergiotulentsev I think he knows that ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton: I think you arrived *after* Pekka edited his comment :)

Comment: @Pekka: `chomp` was shamelessly stolen from [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html). Not that there's anything wrong with that of course.

Comment: @Sergiotulentsev I'm always late to the party :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are only getting the input once, you need to read it at the beginning of each loop, like so:

```
something=""
while something != "BYE"
    puts "Say something to Grandma!"
    something = gets.chomp
    if something == something.upcase
      puts "NO, NOT SINCE 19" + (rand(30..50)).to_s + "!"
    else
      puts "HUH? SPEAK UP SONNY!"
    end
end
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I got the following error when I tried this code: calc.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `something' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: Can you write this using for loop?

Comment: You could, but it wouldn't make much sense. You're looping until a condition is met, not a set number of times. `for` loops should really only be used for looping over a known list or range.